# Disambiguating the thing to which "kiu(n)" and "ĝi(n)" refer

Tags: disambiguation

**Artifika Ekzemplo**

> La aĵo kunpuŝiĝis kun la alia aĵo, kiu kaŭzas ĝin pensi pri vivo.

**La Demando**

Kiel oni distingus...

- ...kiun aferon rilatas la "ĝin"?
- ...kiun rilatas la "kiu" (t.e. ĉu estas la kunpuŝiĝo de la du aĵoj, aŭ unu el la aĵoj, kiu kaŭzas la pensadon de vivo)?

Comment: Tiu ekzemplo estas, por mi, tute ne komprenebla. Ĉu vi povus trovi alian?

Comment: Tiu stranga ekzemplo ankaŭ aplikeblus al la angla, kiel "The thing bumped into the other thing, which caused it to think about life". Mi provos trovi alian ekzemplon.

Comment: Sed _kunpuŝiĝi_ ne akceptas tiun -n finaĵon. Kaj _kaŭzi sin_ estas ne vere komprenebla, unuavide. Kaj en la traduko de tiu angla frazo, vi neniel uzus _sin_ ĉar nenio estas objekto de sia propra ago. Nu, klopodi klarigi _sin_ aŭ _kiu_ en tia frazo estas neutila klopodo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antaŭ ol respondi vian demandon, mi volas rimarkigi al vi, ke via frazo havas du malgrandajn problemojn:

> La aĵo kunpuŝiĝis kun la alia aĵo, kiu kaŭzas ĝin pensi pri vivo.

Vi menciis la anglan originalon:

> The thing bumped into the other thing, which caused it to think about life.

El tiu frazo ni povas dedukti, ke *kiu* verŝajne fakte rilatas al la kunpuŝiĝo de la du aĵoj kaj ne al unu el la du aĵoj; do *kiu* devas esti *kio*:

> La aĵo kunpuŝiĝis kun la alia aĵo, **kio** kaŭzas ĝin pensi pri vivo.

Mi ne uzus *kaŭzi* kun *ĝin* kiel objekto, ĉar la afero kaŭzata ne estas *ĝin*, sed *ke ĝi pensas pri vivo*. Do mi uzus *igi* aŭ ŝanĝus la frazon al *kio kaŭzas, ke ĝi pensas pri vivo*.

> La aĵo kunpuŝiĝis kun la alia aĵo, kio **igas** ĝin pensi pri vivo.

Por vere respondi vian demandon: La frazo simple estas ambigua pri tio, al kio rilatas *ĝin*, samkiel la angla originalo. Oni alimaniere vortumu la frazon por diri pli ekzakte tion, kion oni volas. Ekzemple:

> Pro sia kunpuŝiĝo kun la alia aĵo la aĵo pensas pri vivo.

(Malgraŭ, ke la ripetiĝo de *aĵo* estas malbela) la ĉi-supra ekzemplo kongruas kun la originalo, kie *ĝin* rilatas al la unua aĵo.

> La aĵo kunpuŝiĝas kun la alia aĵo, kio igas ĉi tiun pensi pri vivo.

Ĉi tiu ekzemplo kongruas kun la originalo, kie *ĝin* rilatas al la dua aĵo.

Esperanto simple povas esti ambigua en diversaj situacioj, samkiel aliaj lingvoj. Oni kelkfoje devas revortumi ion kaj uzi pli da vortoj aŭ pli specifajn vortojn por senambiguigi frazon.

Answer (score 1):

Se oni konsideras la strukturon de via ekzemplo, kaj vian demandon, la respondo estus:

- *kiu* estas [rilata kiu](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/kiu_kio_kies/kiu.html) (multaj ekzemploj tie)
- *sin* en tiu simpla (sub)frazo, rilatas la subjekton de la ago (pli bona klarigo [ĉi tie](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/si/simplaj_frazoj.html)).

Ekzemplo (elpensita):

Tiuj sciencistoj pristudas bestojn, kiuj komunikiĝas inter si per sonoj.

*kiuj* = bestoj
*si* = balenoj

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Joffysloffy, that a rewording of the example is in order.

A more general answer…

IFAIK there are no steadfast rules about references. In the Lernu forum someone constructed an example:

> - Mi vizitis la **palacon** de la reĝino de Anglio, **kiu** nomiĝas Windsor Castle.
> - Mi vizitis la palacon de la **reĝino** de Anglio, **kiu** nomiĝas Elizabeto II.
> - Mi vizitis la palacon de la reĝino de **Anglio**, **kiu** estas parto de la Unuiĝinta Reĝlando.

where only the part following "kiu" defines, to which "kiu" actually refers. In languages with a grammatical gender different relative pronouns could ease dechiphering the references, e.g. in German each of those "kiu"s would be different.

Having said that there are a couple of ways to make phrases like your example less ambiguous. Joffysloffy already used these:

- a relative subordinate clause with "kiu" refers to a single word or expression (*palaco, reĝino* or *Anglio* in the example above)
- a relative subordinate clause with "kio" has a less specific references or it refers to a longer expression, even a whole clause like in the modified version of your example *La aĵo kunpuŝiĝis kun la alia aĵo, kio…*
- *ĝi* is usually understood to refer to the subject of the preceding clause
- *ĉi tio/tiu* is usually understood to refer to some non-subject, often object, of the preceding clause

For the last two cases I'm not sure whether that is based on the E-o grammar or just L1 interference.